# Indy 10 Encoding

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I've been facing a problem this morning and simply couldn't solve. I'm trying to send a reply message from a TIdCmdTCPServer to a TIdTCPClient, but I'm getting '?' characters where the message shows non-ANSCII characters. I found out that Indy uses ASCII encoding and tried to change it, to no result. Here's the code:

```
uses IdIOHandler, IdGlobal;

procedure TDMSocket.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TIdIOHandler.DefStringEncoding:= TIdTextEncoding.UTF8;
end;

procedure TDMSocket.IdCmdTCPServerLoginCommand(ASender: TIdCommand);
begin
  [...]
  InformaErros('Usuário ou senha inválidos', ASender);
  [...]
end;

procedure TDMSocket.InformaErros(Erro: string; ASender: TIdCommand);
begin
  ASender.Reply.Text.Text:= Erro;
end;
```

This way, I get the following error:

> Property 'DefStringEncoding' Inacessible Here

Trying to access DefStringEncoding on the IOHandler porperty of IdCmdTCPServer raises the same error. And I didn't get any success with GIdDefaultAnsiEncoding.

What can I do to send the message with the right characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefStringEncoding` is not a **class** property, which is why you cannot access it via the `TIdIOHandler` class type like you attempted to do. It is an **instance** property instead, so you need a pointer to an instance of a `TIdIOHandler` object.

In the `OnCommand` events, you can reach the `TIdIOHandler` object via the `TIdCommand.Context.Connection.IOHandler` property.

If all of your commands and replies will use UTF-8 then it would be better to set `DefStringEncoding` one time when a client connects to the server. You can do that in the `OnConnect` event via the `TIdContext.Connection.IOHandler` property.

As for `GIdDefaultAnsiEncoding`, `TIdIOHandler` only uses it when `DefStringEncoding` is nil, which it is not by default (there is a TODO item to make `TIdIOHandler` use `GIdDefaultAnsiEncoding` when initializing `DefStringEncoding`).